# Why does RMSE underestimate model variance?

Tags: variance, cross-validation, bias, overfitting, rms

I have read that RMSE of calibration/validation/cross validation is frequently used for model selection (e.g., for ANN), but can lead to over-fitting because the prediction error represents the decreasing bias more than the increasing model variance. Empirically, I often observe the RMSE increase with number of model parameters after a certain point, but why does this not sufficiently characterize the variance?

Comment: Can you cite where you read this?

Comment: Not the main point, but note that RMSE and variance are not on the same scale, as variance has the units of the response variable squared, and RMSE has the units of the response. I suspect your question needs rephrasing any way: what precisely is model variance?

Comment: @Kodiologist An example here: (p. 373 first full paragraph) http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cem.883/abstract

Comment: @NickCox Yes, I suppose I could have said MSE, but by variance I mean the non-systematic component of the error as implied in the traditional bias-variance tradeoff discussion.

Comment: As I haven't read the papers that discussion refers to only a comment for now. I think what they say is consistent with this: while a properly done cross validation can be used to characterize an important part of the model variance, this is not done during standard CV procedures. However, for overfitting in data-driven model selection model instability = variance is only one reason. Another important reason is the variance due to the finite set of tested cases. However, both apply to using a fixed test sets as well, and (with varying extent) also to other performance metrics than (R)MSE....

Comment: ... and RMSE is often already more benign in that respect than classification errors like % correct. I'd say the problem is mostly that if you optimize hard with limited test cases, you're skimming variance: the more model/test combinations you check, the more likely you are to find one that is accidentally looking very well.